# Selected div highlight in Html Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i click Test 1,Test 2 or Test 3, clicked div will highlight from other two divs. I want to do is, when div get highlight, other areas of the page must dark ( opacity reduce) Then clicked div only highlight from full page.
Anyone help me to get this done please..

Working sample here

```js
$(function() {
  $('.section').click(function() {
    $('.section2').removeClass('section2');
    $(this).addClass('section2');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: .3;
}

.section2 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px #666;
  border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header>This is header of the sample </header>
  <br/>
  <div class="div-list">
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Test 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Test 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Test 3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <footer>
    <h3>This is footer of the sample </h3>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one of your elements is clicked you can just set black background on he whole container or page with the correct opacity.

```
$(function() {
  $('.section').click(function() {
    $('.section2').removeClass('section2');
    $(this).addClass('section2');
    $(".container").css({"background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"});
  });
});
```

**Updated** JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1jqyk8x/5/

**UPDATE** If you want to get the highlight to disappear you have to write a function that checks if you have clicked on the body but outside of your items.

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.class == "div-list" || $(e.target).parents(".div-list").size()) 
        {
             //This triggers if you click on them
        }
        else
        {     
             //This triggers if you click outside of them
           $(".container").css({"background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0)"});
           $('.section2').removeClass('section2');
        }
  });
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1jqyk8x/6/

Comment: Thanks for reply.
One of element clicked it get dark and opacity": "0.7"  applied.
But opacity": "0.7" applied for highlighted div as well.
I want to apply opacity for .container except to highlighted div.
Any ways to do it?

Comment: Great, it works fine.
one more request please help.
after element clicked it get dark.
Then,When i click on dark area, I mean outside of elements. i want to un selected all element and make ti like first load ( with white background)
Any way to do it?

Comment: I've added the updated code with the new function and a js fiddle example

Comment: Can you accept the answer so it can close the question

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate opacity and Z index of html tag and z-index (higher) of said element that you highlight.

And here is the only code I edited compared to yours:

```
$(function() {
 $('.section').click(function() {
 $('.section2').removeClass('section2');
 $(this).addClass('section2');
 $("html").css({"z-index" : "200", "opacity": "0.7","background": "black"});
});
});


.section2 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin:10px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px #666;
  border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
  z-index: 201;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle url doesn't contain the fiddle itself.

Comment: I used to :( I will remove it, its a simple change and it can be seen in the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1jqyk8x/4/). Please check it out.

What you need to is to add a condition that checks '.section' class if has a class '.section2'.

```
$(function() {
  $('.section').click(function() {
    $('.section2').removeClass('section2');
    $(this).addClass('section2');  
    if ( $('.section').hasClass('section2') ) {
        $('body').addClass('darkBg');
        $('.section2').removeClass('section2');
        $(this).addClass('section2');          
        console.log('aaa');
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('darkBg');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to decrease the opacity of the other items, you could just select all of those, that have no `.section2` class and add a `.darken` class instead.

```js
$(function() {
  $( '.section' ).click(function() {
    $( '.section2' ).removeClass( 'section2 darken' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'section2' );
    $( '.section:not( .section2 )' ).addClass( 'darken' );
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: .3;
  transition: opacity .5s, background-color .25s;
}

.section2 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px #666;
  border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
}

.darken {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header>This is header of the sample </header>
  <br/>
  <div class="div-list">
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Test 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Test 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Test 3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <footer>
    <h3>This is footer of the sample </h3>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Was that what you meant?